# Pandas dataframe map to a new list of objects

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I am new in python, so every tip will be helpful :)

I have a pandas dataframe with multiple columns and I need it converted to a new list of objects. Among all of dataframes columns I have two (lat, lon) that I want in my new object as attributes.

| index | city | lat | lon |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | London | 42.33 | 55.44 |
| 1 | Rome | 92.44 | 88.11 |

My new list of object will need to look something like this:

```
[
  {'lat': 42.33, 'lon': 55.44}, 
  {'lat': 92.44, 'lon': 88.11}
]
```

More specifically I need this for Machine Learning with ML Studio.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Use `Pandas.DataFrame.to_dict(orient)` to convert a DataFrame into a dictionary. There are multiple dictionary orientations; for your case use `orient='records'`

You also want to only select the `lat & lon` columns, like this:

```
df[['lat','lon']].to_dict(orient='records')
```

This will give you your result:

```
[{'lat': 42.33, 'lon': 55.44}, {'lat': 92.44, 'lon': 88.11}]
```

Here are some other orientations you could try out:

```
‘dict’ (default) : dict like {column -> {index -> value}}

‘list’ : dict like {column -> [values]}

‘series’ : dict like {column -> Series(values)}

‘split’ : dict like {‘index’ -> [index], ‘columns’ -> [columns], ‘data’ -> [values]}

‘records’ : list like [{column -> value}, … , {column -> value}]

‘index’ : dict like {index -> {column -> value}}
```

Comment: Thanks @drew wood. It works:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html

Answer (score 0):

You can choose the columns you want and then use `to_dict` with `orient='records'` to get the required result

`df[["lat", "lon"]].to_dict(orient='records')`

Comment: Thanks @Tom Ron!
I see it now in Pandas Documentation.
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html